# My system has 6 gb ram and i3 processor having ubuntu 12.04 64bit installed

Tags: 12.04

My system has 6 gb ram and i3 processor having ubuntu 12.04 64bit installed. when i starts it works well but after sometime when i poweron VMware and chromium browser memory shows by 
free -m remains just 430 as free and else memory got consumpted by vmware-vmx , vmware, chromium etc i am attaching snapshots of both kindly help me to get rid off this memory overusage issue ? or i have to change the OS to windows or any other Linux Distro :(

Thanks
Raksarora

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The `vmware` processes indicate that you're running virtual machines. Yes, that will consume a lot of memory as they all have their own memory management and caches overhead again. Also, are you looking at the right numbers? `free -m` will show **two** numbers for free memory. Please include more exact (raw) output in your question (edit it). See also: [How can I monitor the memory usage?](http://askubuntu.com/q/9642/88802)

Answer (score 0):

It really is just simple math. You have 6 Gb RAM on the host machine. If you run 2 guest instances (virtual machines) with 2 Gb RAM assigned to each one (2 x 2 = 4 Gb), you end upwith 6 - 4 = 2 Gb available for your host system.

If low memory becomes an issue, you can either install more RAM (if your system can support more RAM) or edit your virtual machines and assign them less RAM.

Comment: Thanks for reply i have just one VM with xp installed in it and 768 mb has given to it. when i started to work with chromium and near 10 tabs were opened then simultaneously system starts got hanged.i have given 6 gb swap space as well.but i think that has no use ? my ram was 2 gb before then i upgrade it and now its 6 gb kindly clarify me and suggest the best solution .http://askubuntu.com/users/150902/hmayag