# Is there a way to collect RAM usage stats?

Tags: 16.04, performance, ram

This is my configuration:

```
Processor: Intel Core i5-2500K @ 3.70GHz (4 Cores), 
Motherboard: ASRock H67DE3, Chipset: Intel 2nd Generation Core Family 
DRAM, Memory: 32768MB, 
Disk: 250GB Samsung SSD 850, 
Graphics: HIS AMD Radeon HD 6870 1024MB, 
Audio: Realtek ALC892, 
Monitor: SyncMaster, 
Network: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411

Ubuntu 16.04
```

I have discovered that java consumes a lot of RAM but I need to understand how to collect the RAM usage per software application.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9642/how-can-i-monitor-the-memory-usage

Comment: @Rinzwind sorry but I need a RAM statistics per time period and per software application

Comment: Have you tried htop?  You may have to install it.  It breaks down CPU and RAM usage for each task, and allows you to sort on whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using smemstat?  Running it once will show you the memory usage at that instance, where as running it in periodic mode will show the memory delta of processes over time:

one shot mode:

```
smemstat
```

period mode (say every 60 seconds for 100 samples:)

```
smemstat 60 100
```

Comment: thanks it is a good start, but I need  a statistics per time period and per software application