# editing the config file about total threads that can be run on ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, server, process

I have seen in my  ubuntu  server that the value of  threads-max is 129573.Then  i run myprogram and after a while  the terminal shows  the error with-: system error:resource temporarily  unavailabe.Then i see my  total  threads  which is running  in my os which prints  out 32509.I printed  it out with the command ps -A |wc -l .I have also  tried to set  the process limit  in  /etc/security/limits.cnf  and  have set  it  to the value of  threads-max but still  i am getting  this error.(by the count it shows that  i havent reached the threshold limit,so how am i getting this error?).
Thanks,
Kushal

Comment: this is the value that i have  set in /etc/security/limits.conf
<b>
*     soft    nproc           127932
*     hard    nproc           127932
</b>

Comment: Please edit the question to show the result of the more detailed command line, where you are not only counting the processes, but the threads (some processes own more than one thread). From `info ps`, `nlwp        NLWP      number of lwps (threads) in the process.  (alias thcount)`

Comment: Please see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845380/bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882624/max-number-of-simaltenous-running-process). I was able to get 118000 threads on my test computer.

Comment: i ran ps -eo nlwp | tail -n +2 | awk '{ num_threads += $1 }   this  command  to get total number  of threads  running  on  the  system

Comment: @DougSmythies could  you  please  elaborate  about  how  you did it ?

Comment: I do not know what else to add beyond what is already written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845380/bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable/883677#883677). Keep in mind, my getting to 118000 threads took some effort and actually each task did virtually nothing and used virtually no memory and my system was still on the verge of collapse. I'm saying my test was more academic than showing an actual useful thread limit where real work could also be done.

Comment: ok so   was  all  ur  threads  alive  all  the  time ?

Comment: actually thats  the  main concern  of mine  :(  all  my threads  remain  idle  for  some  work  to happen  gets  activated  when  thereis work  so  these  threads  are alive  all  the  time  in that  way

Comment: My threads were mostly sleeping. I also did other tests with less and less sleep, but do not recall the limits for those tests. I think you will just have to test your particular use case with your computer to learn what it can handle.

Comment: its still not  working  for  me  :( is there any other alternative  for  this  problem?

Comment: hey,do   u remember  about  whether  the  number of  thread count decreased  or not  with  ur  different   test  cases?