# Cannot fork (for cron jobs), but ulimit and RAM looks fine

Tags: cron, ulimit

Several cron jobs keep failing to execute because the kernel cannot fork. It's been happening for weeks (I think since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16 but possibly earlier).

## Error messages

```
 $ grep fork myscript.log
/usr/bin/groovy: 24: /usr/bin/groovy: Cannot fork

$ tail /var/log/syslog
Oct 19 14:25:01 nuc CRON[19939]: (CRON) error (can't fork)
Oct 19 14:25:01 nuc cron[719]: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Note: I don't care about `sendmail` specifically.

## Environment info

### ulimit -a

```
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        8192
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              999999
nofiles              999999
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited
rtprio               0
```

### cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

```
7936    0   793377
```

### cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max

```
32768
```

### htop

```
  1  [|||                                                                                                       1.9%]   Tasks: 196, 114 kthr; 1 running
  2  [|||||                                                                                                     4.2%]   Load average: 0.43 0.20 0.16
  3  [|                                                                                                         0.7%]   Uptime: 2 days, 18:22:08
  4  [                                                                                                          0.0%]
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 5.68G/7.62G]
  Swp[|||||||                                                                                             218M/3.82G]
```

### uname -a

```
Linux nuc 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Other relevant information

- It mostly seems to happen in cron. When I run it interactively (usually in `zsh`) the job runs fine.
- I'm running dozens of groovy microservices (and each thread opens its own file handle to each jar file).
- I started using Docker out of desperation, but it's just making it more difficult to see which ports are currently being listened on.

Comment: There are other places that limit things. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882624/max-number-of-simaltenous-running-process) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845380/bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable). Oh, I see via your edit that you are probably out of memory.

Comment: Actually it was happening even when I was using less than 4GB. Thanks, I'll take a look at your links.