# How to increase maxium number of forks in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, docker, sh, nohup

I am attempting to spin up 1000x Docker containers via:

```
nohup docker run --rm --name n-$1-$2 n-v2 bash -c "/root/sw/run.sh $1 $2" 2> ~/logs/log-$1-$2.log &
```

But after about 500x containers I start getting the following error:

```
fork: retry: No child processes
```

The server I am running this on has 48x cores and 192 GB of ram ... I should be able to spin up several thousand of these containers with no problem ... is there a way to increase this limit?

After doing some googling I found that I can check the number of max forks via `ulimit -u` ... is there a way to change this?

`Soren A`'s answer seems legit, however it doesnt seem like this solved the issue.  I can get to ~12287 threads (checed via `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.current`) before I start hitting the same issue ...  both my hard and soft limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are set to `99999999` yet I am still being capped at around `12287`

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/845380/bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable/883677#883677)

Comment: So, increase `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max` as explained in the answer I pointed you to. I just had 118205 simultaneous processes running on my computer, although it took some doing.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank You, your answer solved it ... 1000x nodes 15095 threads

Comment: I rolled back the addition of the answer to the question post. If you solved your problem based on an existing answer in a linked question please vote for that answer to increase its visibility. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values temporary with `ulimit -u <value>` 
Or permanently in /etc/security/limits.conf with lines like

```
*    hard    nproc  64000
*    soft    nproc  64000
```

Or the same in a ,conf file in /etc/security/limits.d, ex. /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf if you like.

Instead of setting it for all users (*) you could do it only for the user starting your processes, so that other users can't grab that many resources on your system.

Comment: I tried this with and without sudo and got errors both times `-bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted` & `sudo: ulimit: command not found`

Comment: Yes, a normal user can't go above the 'hard limit' .. you will have to set nproc in the limit.conf file .. and reboot. And ulimit can'tbe set in sudo.

Comment: still getting this issue when I go above 12287 threads (checked via `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.current`)

Comment: I can't see what limit you are hitting, but for all ulimit limits the above method works.