# Output of "free -m" doesn't match

Tags: command-line, ram, memory-usage, free

How can I check my RAM usage? I am trying the command `free -m` as I saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9642/how-can-i-monitor-the-memory-usage), I should get something like this:

```
              total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3699       2896        802          0        247       1120
-/+ buffers/cache:       1528       2170
Swap:         1905         62       1843
```

But when I try this command I can't see the line: `-/+ buffers/cache:    1528    2170`

I always get:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7903        2395         142         341        5365        4710
Swap:          6541          21        6520
```

So, where I can see my free and used RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated `free -m` output is different from the referenced 2010 post you pointed at.

The 'Available' value is the one you want to look at; it takes into account the buffers and cache now.  So in your system, you have 4710MB of memory available out of 7903MB of available memory on your system.