# Any browser tends to freeze Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, freeze

Any browser tends to freeze ubuntu 20.04 OS upgrade. This apparently happens once or twice every other update, upgrade, dist-upgrade and etc...dating back went UBUNTU was some Linux favor.  Beside reloading the operating disk from scratch, can they start working on this. Here is some research:  [Ubuntu 18.04 hangs when using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043012/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-when-using-google-chrome-mozilla-firefox-and-thunderbird)

Comment: Would help if you can edit your question with the computer info found on the the link.  Can you say this does not happen between updates and mention if it is any update or just updates of browsers?